# Why is it common to mark record fields with UNPACK and strictness?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I noticed this pattern is very common in Haskell libraries:

```
data Foo = Foo { field :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Sometype }
```

e.g. `UNPACK`ing a field's type and making it strict.

I understand what's the effect of the pragma and annotation but I don't understand why it is so pervasive: I have been programming in Haskell for 15 years and seldom used strictness annotation, and never `UNPACK` pragma.

If this idiom is so useful, why not make it less "ugly"?

Comment: I suspect it is often legacy leftover, since [`-funbox-small-strict-fields` is on by default since ghc 7.8](http://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.1/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--funbox-small-strict-fields)

Comment: I have also been programming haskell for 12 years and seldom use such annotations, then again I have never dived into squeezing every last millisecond out of a piece of haskell code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pragma may be a bit ugly, but it avoids a lot *more* ugliness elsewhere. When performance is critical, programmers often need to choose a particular shape for a data constructor. Suppose I have

```
data Point = Point Int Int
data Segment = Segment Point Point
```

That makes good logical sense, but it has a bunch of extra indirection: one `Segment` consists of *seven* heap objects. If I'm working with a lot of segments, that's pretty bad.

I could squash this flat by hand:

```
data Segment = Segment Int# Int# Int# Int#
```

but now I've lost the fact that the numbers represent points, and everything I do with a segment will have to involve rather inconvenient and weird unboxed operations.

Fortunately, there's a better way:

```
-- The small strict Int fields will be unpacked by default
-- with any reasonably recent GHC version.
data Point = Point !Int !Int

data Segment = Segment {-# UNPACK #-} !Point {-# UNPACK #-} !Point
```

This still gives me one heap object per segment, but I can use `Point`s and `Int`s and (generally) rely on the compiler unboxing everything nicely.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `UNPACK` requires `!`? And this is only ever needed for performance reasons (in terms of memory consumption and/or GC overhead and/or CPU time spent boxing/unboxing)?

Comment: @insitu, yes, only strict fields can be unpacked. Lazy ones need those extra heap objects to preserve semantics. And yes, `UNPACK` only affects performance. The  rule of thumb is that small things should be unpacked and large things shouldn't be, but it really depends on context.

Comment: I guess my next question would be: Why is it common to make all fields of records strict? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @insitu, one reason is to allow unpacking. The other main one is to avoid space leaks and excess allocation. Laziness is usually either essential for performance or detrimental to it.